How to Recreate SharePoint Document Library Structure in Power Apps
I have a Document library named "Project Details" with different files and folders with different columns. I have also added some files inside folders, like the one below.

Now, I would like to recreate this same document Library structure: [When the user clicks on a specific folder, it will display the respective files. Otherwise, it will display all the files and folders.]
Could you please give any solution...
